# How can I remove a value in this list if it is not inside one of the keys of this nested dictionary?

Tags: python

Currently, I have the following weird nested dictionary:

```
d = {'start': {'0': {'start', 'near'}, '1': {'start'}}, 'near': {'1': {'end'}}, 'end': {}}
```

And the following list:

```
l = ['1', '0', '1', 'x', '0', '1']
```

If one of the values in `l` are not in one of the keys and values in the dictionary, remove it from the list.

So for example, in the list, there is an "x" and I am trying to see if there is anyway I can remove it with either `l.remove()` or if `del` / `pop` is better.

The thing that is giving me troubles is the dictionary.

---

**What I have going so far:**

```
d = {'start': {'0': {'start', 'near'}, '1': {'start'}}, 'near': {'1': {'end'}}, 'end': {}}
l = ['1', '0', '1', 'x', '0', '1']

for key, value in d.items():
    for keys, values in value.items():
        for number in l:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the set of keys:

```
keys = set.union(*[set(x.keys()) for x in d.values()])
#{'0', '1'}
```

Filter out the non-keys:

```
result = [item for item in l if item in keys]
#['1', '0', '1', '0', '1']
```

Comment: What about subtracting `keys` from `set(l)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist You cannot intersect a list and a set without losing the order of the list.

Comment: That's true. Removal is more painful than filtering in this case.